# blkid + print only the disks that are with filesystem

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, redhat-enterprise-linux, redhat-classic

regarding blkid command

please help me to approve this assumption

can we say that blkid will print all disk devices only if these disks are with filesystem (  by mkfs )

```
blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="cc749f07-ad00-49e8-ab19-eceef99f5e28" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="v0593a-KiKU-9emb-STbx-ByMz-S95k-jChr0m" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="9b44be8e-fa59-4d84-ada5-1345498663ba" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc: UUID="239505a3-8fb2-4da9-9edd-465299ce15c0" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sde: UUID="986cd2f3-4d5d-4431-a221-30b142a61c7c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdf: UUID="b8c3c3db-7e13-47b9-b4f9-f706a5223b76" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdd: UUID="3c3730ec-d23a-4d1b-8880-224eb658d3ab" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root: UUID="a8c48724-98b7-44b4-89ac-28214462638c" 
TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_swap: UUID="1beb675f-0b4c-4225-8455-e876cafc5756" 
TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_var: UUID="3de01172-29a2-4b5f-9aef-f9b3032eb7c5" TYPE="xfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default blkid will list *all* block devices, including those without a file system on them.

You maybe able to filter the results of blkid or lsblk to give you what you want, but as you've not actually specified what you're looking for, I cannot currently help further.

Comment: but when disk is not over mkfs then UUID not displayed only after mkfs , so this is good example that UUID will be only after make file system

Comment: what we need is all disks that without mkfs